# Toggle Fast Charging option using code in Android

Tags: android, batterymanager

I have a Samsung phone with an option to enable/disable Fast Charging (Cable) option. Can I do the same programmatically inside an Android app? 
I looked inside BatteryManager class documentation but it does not have an option to check whether Fast Charging is enabled or not. 
Please suggest.

Comment: Hi, was you able to figure out how to do this?